# Menu button triggering another window

Tags: c++, window, win32gui

I am new to c++ and have started to get my head around Win32 GUI. I am trying to make a sub menu button open a window that will display a calculator window, however I can't seem to figure it out by doing the logical thing and I can't find anything useful online. Please Help! P.S It wants me to write more detail so... I have tried to use the CreateWindowW() function in the WM_COMMAND windows procedure with the case that the command is the same as the ID of the button. However, while it does still run, it fails to actually do anything.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define FILE_MENU_NEW 1
#define FILE_MENU_OPEN 2
#define FILE_MENU_EXIT 3

#define ID_GO 4

#define BUTTON_CALCULATOR 5

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

void AddMenus(HWND);
void AddControls(HWND);

HMENU hMenu;
HWND login;
HWND button;
HWND usernameText;
HWND passwordText;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args,int ncmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if(!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass",L"My Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,100,100,1000,800,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    MSG msg = {0};

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(wp)
        {
        case FILE_MENU_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;
        case FILE_MENU_NEW:
            break;
        case ID_GO:
            //Work in progress
            wchar_t usernameInput[100];
            wchar_t passwordInput[100];
            GetWindowTextW(usernameText,usernameInput,100);
            GetWindowTextW(passwordText,passwordInput,100);
            break;
        case BUTTON_CALCULATOR:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            CreateWindowW(L"calculatorClass",L"Calculator", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,100,100,500,500,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
    }
}

void AddMenus(HWND hWnd)
{
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hToolMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hSubMenu,MF_STRING,NULL,"Note");

    AppendMenu(hFileMenu,MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)hSubMenu,"New");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu,MF_STRING,FILE_MENU_OPEN,"Open");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu,MF_SEPARATOR,NULL,NULL);
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu,MF_STRING,FILE_MENU_EXIT,"Exit");

    AppendMenu(hToolMenu,MF_STRING,BUTTON_CALCULATOR,"Calculator");

    AppendMenu(hMenu,MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)hFileMenu,"File");
    AppendMenu(hMenu,MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)hToolMenu,"Tools");

    SetMenu(hWnd,hMenu);
}

void AddControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Login:",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD| SS_RIGHT, 50,50,80,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    usernameText = CreateWindowW(L"edit",L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 140,50,80,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Password:",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD| SS_RIGHT, 50,90,80,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    passwordText = CreateWindowW(L"edit",L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 140,90,80,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    button = CreateWindowW(L"button", L"GO", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,250,65,50,30,hWnd,(HMENU)ID_GO,NULL,NULL);
}
```

Comment: What EXACTLY are you having trouble with?  It is unclear what the real problem is.

Comment: As it states in the description, I am trying to get a window to open when a menu button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WM_COMMAND` handler is checking the `WPARAM` value incorrectly.

The LOWORD of the `WPARAM` value contains the ID of the item that is sending the `WM_COMMAND` message, and the `HIWORD` contains the notification code, such as `BN_CLICKED`, etc.  You are ignoring the `HIWORD` completely.  Your `switch(wp)` statement will only work for menu items, where the `HIWORD` is 0, but it will not work for things like button clicks, where the HIWORD is not 0.  Your `ID_GO` control is a button, not a menu item, so the `wp` argument will never be exactly `ID_GO` for your `switch(wp)` statement to find a `case` for.

At the very least, you need to change `switch(wp)` to `switch(LOWORD(wp))` instead:

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wp))
        {
        case FILE_MENU_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;

        case FILE_MENU_NEW:
            break;

        case ID_GO:
            {
            //Work in progress
            wchar_t usernameInput[100];
            wchar_t passwordInput[100];
            GetWindowTextW(usernameText,usernameInput,100);
            GetWindowTextW(passwordText,passwordInput,100);
            }
            break;
        }

        case BUTTON_CALCULATOR:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            CreateWindowW(L"calculatorClass",L"Calculator", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,100,100,500,500,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But, more importantly, there is no call to `RegisterClassW()` for the `"calculatorClass"` window class, eg:

```c
WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hInstance = hInst;
wc.lpszClassName = L"calculatorClass";
wc.lpfnWndProc = CalculatorWindowProcedure;

RegisterClassW(&wc)
```

How do you expect `CreateWindowW()` to create a window for a class it does not know about?  Your code is not checking the `CreateWindowW()` call for failure either, eg:

```c
hCalcWnd = CreateWindowW(L"calculatorClass",L"Calculator", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,100,100,500,500,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
if (!hCalcWnd)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError(); // ERROR_CLASS_DOES_NOT_EXIST, etc...
    ...
}
```

---

On a side note, you are not assigning an ID to your `"Note"` item on the `File|New` sub-menu.  And for consistency with your `File` menu items, you should consider renaming `BUTTON_CALCULATOR` to something like `TOOL_MENU_CALCULATOR`.  And maybe rename `ID_GO` to `BUTTON_GO`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this fixes the problem. My ID_GO isn't the button that I am trying to open a new window. I'm trying top get the menu button, that is classed (BUTTON_CALCULATOR) to trigger the window. I tried the suggested HIWORD and LOWORD and it has just given me errors. I know that this is probably obvious to a person who isn't new to c++ but I am lost. p.s thank you for the side note.

Comment: What errors exactly? Please be more specific. And did you step through the code with a debugger to make sure the `WM_COMMAND` is being received and the `switch/case` statements are doing what you are expecting? And where is your registeration of the `"calculatorClass"` window class? Your code is not checking the `CreateWindowW()` call for failure.

Comment: The first is "duplicate case value" bringing me to the "case BN_CLICKED:"

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realize `BN_CLICKED` is defined as 0. You should still use `LOWORD` in `switch (LOWORD(wp))` when checking the IDs, though. I updated my answer